# Solving an integral (with substitution?)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For a physical problem I have to solve $\sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}\int_0^{2\pi /a}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{U}{E} \tan^2(ax))^{1/2}}dx $

I already tried substituting $1-\frac{U}{E}\tan^2(ax)$ and $\frac{U}{E}\tan^2(ax)$ since $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = \arcsin(x)$ but my problem is that $dx$ changes to something with $\cos^2(ax)$, thus making the integral not easier.

Anyone got a hint?

**EDIT**: The physical problem is to calculate the oscillating period given an potential $V(x) = U \tan^2(ax) $ by using conservation of energy. Here's what I did so far:

$E_{kin} + V(x) = E $

$=> \frac12 m (\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = E-V(x)$

$=>\int_{0}^{T}dt = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}\int_{0}^{2\pi/a} \frac{dx}{(1-U/E \tan^2(ax))^{1/2}}$

Comment: Replace the $\tan$ by a new variable. Since the derivative of the $\arctan$ is rational, you get an integral of the form $\int R(x,\sqrt{az^2+bz+c})$ where $R$ is rational. Then use [Euler substirutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).

Comment: Can you go more in detail with that? Because it doesn't solve my problem that $dx$ changes to something with $cos^2(ax)$

Comment: Are you really sure the period is given by such an integral? What happens when $\tan^2(\alpha x)>\frac{E}{U}$? The square root is not defined in such a case.

Comment: I will edit the original task

Comment: I rewrote [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1129862/85343) a few days ago. I'll like you take a look at that and ignores the wrong comment at it.

Comment: @FelixMarin How is the comment to your answer "wrong", in any sense of the term? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did It may have become obsolete by the rewriting of the answer. (I haven't checked the new calculations, they may be correct or incorrect.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, and this is not what this OP is saying.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just work with $$I:=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b\tan^2(ax)}}dx$$

Once you get this primitive you know how to compute your definite integral.

Let's put $y=\tan(ax)$. Then $x=\frac{1}{a}\arctan(y)$, and $dx=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy$.

Then $$I=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-by^2}}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy.$$

We can use an [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) such that $\sqrt{1-by^2}=yz-1$ (the second type).

Then $1-by^2=y^2z^2-2yz+1$. From where $0=yz^2-2z +by$. We get then that $$\begin{align}y&=\frac{2z}{z^2+b}\\dy&=\frac{2b-2z^2}{(z^2+b)^2}dz\\\sqrt{1-by^2}&=\frac{2z}{z^2+b}\cdot z-1\end{align}$$

Putting this into the integral we get 
$$I=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{\frac{2z}{z^2+b}\cdot z-1}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{2z}{z^2+b}\right)^2}\frac{2b-2z^2}{(z^2+b)^2}dz$$

Observe how this is only the integral of a rational function. You can use simple fraction decomposition to compute it. Personally, I would give this last to a computer to do it for me.

Comment: How do you get  from $\sqrt{1-by^2}$ to $\frac{2z}{z^2+b}z-1$ ?

Comment: Okay, I see by using $\sqrt{1-by^2}=yz-1$, I got stuck with it because I wanted to substitute $y$ in $\sqrt{1-by^2}$ with $y=\frac{2z}{z^2+b}$

Comment: @Christian Yes. I tried leaving it without simplification so you can see where it is coming from. Where were you getting that $\cos^2(ax)$ that you were saying?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
I guess the OP is considering an application of the *BS-quantization rule*.
Indeed the original question is not right at all. You should consider an interval,
along the $\ds{x}$-axis, where the kinetic energy is $\ds{\geq 0}$. It defines the 'returning points' $\ds{\braces{x}}$ which are given by $\ds{U\tan^{2}\pars{ax}=E}$.

Hereafter we'll assume that $\ds{U > 0}$ such that the energy $\ds{E}$ is a positive quantity $\ds{\pars{~E > 0~}}$. For simplicity we'll assume the 'problem' is 'confined' to symmetrical returning points which are given by $\ds{\pm\,\tilde{x}}$ where
$\ds{\tilde{x} = \frac{1}{a}\,\arctan\pars{\root{\frac{E}{U}}}}$.

There isn't any essential difficult whenever we consider a more general situation. 
We are lead to evaluate:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\int_{-\tilde{x}}^{\tilde{x}}
\frac{\dd x}{\bracks{1 -U\tan^{2}\pars{ax}/E}^{1/2}}}
=\frac{2}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2E}} \ \overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{a\tilde{x}}\frac{\dd x}{\bracks{1 -U\tan^{2}\pars{x}/E}^{1/2}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{\tan\pars{x}}\equiv\dsc{t}\ \imp\ \dsc{x}=\dsc{\arctan\pars{t}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\frac{2}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\root{E/U}}
\frac{\dd t}{\bracks{1 -Ut^{2}/E}^{1/2}\pars{t^{2} + 1}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{t}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{\frac{1}{t}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\frac{2}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{\root{U/E}}^{\infty}
\frac{t\,\dd t}{\bracks{t^{2} -U/E}^{1/2}\pars{t^{2} + 1}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{t^{2}}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{t}}}
=\frac{1}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\ \overbrace{\int_{U/E}^{\infty}
\frac{\dd t}{\bracks{t -U/E}^{1/2}\pars{t + 1}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{\pars{t - U/E}^{1/2}}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{t}}}
\\[5mm]&=\frac{2}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{\dd t}{t^{2} + U/E + 1}
=\frac{2}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\frac{1}{\root{1 + U/E}}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{\dd t}{t^{2} +  1}}^{\dsc{\frac{\pi}{2}}}
\end{align}

---

Finally,
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\root{\frac{m}{2E}}\int_{-\tilde{x}}^{\tilde{x}}
\frac{\dd x}{\bracks{1 -U\tan^{2}\pars{ax}/E}^{1/2}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\frac{\pi}{a}\root{\frac{m}{2\pars{E + U}}}}
\end{align}
This result together with the BS-quantization rules provides an expression for the energy $\ds{E}$.

> I suggest that, next time, you post this kind of question in [Physics StackExchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is plagued by errors. A hint that something went astray is the square root of a negative number at the end (but already the second line is wrong).